# How to modify contextmenu in jstree to get rid of unwanted space and align material icon with the text?

Tags: html, css, jstree

Part of my contextmenu is:

```
'contextmenu': {
    items: function ($node) {
        return {
            'addnew': {
                "label": '<span class="material-symbols-outlined mr-2">add_circle</span>Add folder',
                "action": function (obj) {
                    AddNewFolder()
                }
            },
```

Visually it looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to get rid of unwanted space marked with red cross and align icon and text center-vertically. Any advise will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Inspect css styles / classes of the element in question.

Comment: <li class=""><a href="#" rel="0"><i></i><span class="vakata-contextmenu-sep">&nbsp;</span><span class="material-symbols-outlined mr-2">add_circle</span>Add folder</a></li>

Comment: Look at `ul` (parent of your `li`) and its `margin-left` property.

Comment: <ul class="vakata-context jstree-contextmenu jstree-default-contextmenu" style="left: 326.203px; top: 187.348px; display: block;"><li class=""...
</ul>

Comment: ul {
    display: block; (crossed in google styles dev.tools)
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

Comment: Now look at `vakata-context jstree-contextmenu jstree-default-contextmenu` css class property.

Comment: .vakata-context, .vakata-context ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #979797;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
}

Interesting that jstree-xxx styles are not shown in "Styles" tab of Google devtools.

Comment: Play with `padding-inline-start: 40px; `

Comment: Now I have this:
`ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
`,
where padding-inline-start and display-block are crossed
and this:
`ul {
    padding-inline-start: 5px;
}`

Visual output did not change